# How to make an app restart on quit in macOS

Tags: macos

*Question:*
what are some approaches to have an application restart whenever it quits?

*Premise:* I have a background application, A, that runs nicely, but unexpectedly quits cleanly every now and then. Lately I have installed an application, B, that relies on A, to keep functioning. Problematically neither A nor B alerts me that A has quit. I don't have access to the source of any of these applications, so I'm looking for a solution outside of the respective applications. Which is also why I haven't named them, as the solution should be relevant to all such problems.

Comment: The usual way is a [launchd daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Comment: Thanks, @MaciejS. Are you referring to something specific from the instructions?

Comment: @Max sorry bro - I missed your sentence: "I don't have access to the source of any of these applications, so I'm looking for a solution outside of the respective applications."

Comment: No worries, @MaciejS.

Comment: Thanks, @vadian, I will look into launchd daemons.